# How to remove old DOM content when *ngIf is triggered for the second time

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have an Angular 2 component that looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="Data"> This is my data: {{Data}} </div>
```

Which outputs (Pretending that Data is just a string saying "Data" for convenience)

```
This is my data: Data
```

In my controller's OnInit function I subscribe to an observable that updates this Data object from time to time. 
My Controller's onInit function looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataEvent.subscribe(Data=> this.Data = Data);
}
```

When the update happens, the component realises there has been a change, and displays the new data. But does not clear the old data, so I end up with:

```
This is my data: DataThis is my data: NewData
```

I am trying to clear that DOM element before rendering the new data such that my component should just display

```
This is my data: NewData
```

After the observable triggers the update. I have similar issues with *ngFor as well but I assume there would be a common solution to both.

Comment: I guess you will need to provide some more code in order to be able to help you. Because what you show and what you describe does not fit together. The behaviour from what I can see here, should not be as described. So the bug has to be somewhere else. For example in the markup of your component tieing things together.

Comment: That's what I feared. I've 0 experience with Angular and next to no frontend/javascript experience until about 2 days ago when I got landed with an unfinished codebase from an employee that was leaving. I'll see if I can figure out what other aspects are relevant to beef up my question. This behaviour occurs in a good few places, all tied to subscribe events on a variety of html components so I hoped it was a pretty generic issue rather than something specific to a weird case I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was stupid and didn't heed a console warning I should have. I was running typescript 2.6.0 but the angular project I was working on required an older version. The warning was:

```
@angular/compiler-cli@4.3.6 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 2.6.0 was found instead. 

Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems. 

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript. 

    npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' 

To disable this warning run "ng set --global warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
```

And simply running:

```
npm install typescript@2.3.4
```

Solved my issue immediately. Hope this helps someone else not waste hours of their life trying to debug a problem when the warning literally says that it can cause difficult to debug problems >.<